# SQL : How to update table Automatically in 2nd database when table in 1st database is updated?

Tags: mysql, triggers, automation

I have database `db1` and `db2` having the table `mytable` on both the databases in same server.

Both the table contains exactly the same columns.

For Ex:

```
SNo  |  fname  |   lname  | Mobile | Status
```

Both the table has a column name `Status`

What should I do so that when value of column `Status` is updated in table `mytable` in database `db1` then value of column `Status` is updated AUTOMATICALLY in table `mytable` in database `db2`

I don't know what actually it is called. Perhaps Trigger !

Comment: Hi @irfan i added the answer. Please check the update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a trigger in Mysql.

Example:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;
```

I am using the above trigger to update two tables.

Have a look on this [tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php)

**update**

You can not trigger on a particular column update in SQL, it is applied on a row.

You can put your condition for column inside your trigger like below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  TRIGGER  myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON db1.mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

if NEW.Status <> OLD.Status
then

update db2.mytable set Status = NEW.Status where sno = OLD.sno;

END if;

END $$
```

Comment: If any other column updated then there should not be any change. Only if "Status" column is updated then there should be change. Also if row in db1 table is deleted then it should not delete the row in db2. I want only Status column updation ! How to do that ?

Comment: If other column updates occurs then if it triggers update then also no problem. I actually I don't need it but if it happens then no problem. Only problem is it should not trigger delete if the row is deleted !

Comment: Can you give me the exact code. I am very new to it and I don't know what  and how to do. But I need it urgently.

Comment: Hi @IrfanAlam i added the solution

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check it, if it will work then I will accept your answer as correct. If not then I will reply you.

Comment: There is syntax error. I am not able to execute it.

Comment: What syntax error. Where did you get it. Did you add  ;

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin  update db2.mytable set status = NEW.Status 
where sno = OLD.sno' at line 5

Comment: No I have not added anything like ;

Comment: Hi @IrfanAlam, Please check the code now. In the if statement i made the mistake

Comment: It was returning this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 1